# i keep getting an undefined error when running this code

Tags: python, try-catch, undefined

```
import sys                                                                                                                                          
looptwo = True
while looptwo == True:
  print("Welcome to the junior maths program, this program helps you do    maths problems and acts as a calulator.")                                      
  try:
    name = input("What is your name? ")                                                                                                             
    number = int(input("Enter your first number: "))                                                                                                
    number2 = int(input("Enter your second number: "))
  except ValueError:
    print("that is not an option")
    looptwo == False
```

when i run this code, it says that number isn't defined.

Comment: Looks defined to me. You didn't make one of your in-code comments a comment though.

Comment: `looptwo == False` should be `looptwo = False`. Apart form this this code seems to work. Also the code is an infinte loop, if no valueerror occurs. Not sure this is your intention?

Comment: Include the actual exception with line numbers in your question.

Answer (score 2):

Your logic is backwards, you should only break if there is no error, you set `looptwo` equal to `False` in the except presuming that `==` is a typo which breaks the loop. So whenever you try to access `name` etc.. outside when the loop after an exception you will get an undefined error.
The **only** way your code breaks is when an exception is raised:

Use while True and only break if there were no exceptions.

```
while True:
    print("Welcome to the junior maths program, this program helps you do    maths problems and acts as a calulator.")
    try:
        name = input("What is your name? ")
        number = int(input("Enter your first number: "))
        number2 = int(input("Enter your second number: "))
        break
    except ValueError:
        print("that is not an option")
```